# kubernetes strategic merge patch

Tags: rest, kubernetes, json-patch, kubelet

Hi I am following this doc https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/api-conventions.md#strategic-merge-patch for strategic-merge-patch to partially update the JSON objects using PATCH REST API. The document says that it can add or delete the object, but I have tried, whenever I add new object to existing JSON it just replaces that instead of adding new. I am trying this to modify pod definition in OpenShift 3.2.  can anyone please help me how it works, probably with example. I need to use delete operation also , where I can delete the value by name.

Comment: Can you provide example JSON files?

Comment: Please provide the JSON files you are trying to PATCH. It's easier to help or let you know where you are going wrong. :)

Answer (score 3):

As documented it depends on annotations of the types. AFAIS the strategic merge only works if `patchStrategy` and `patchMergeKey` are given. For example, this is the case in [`pod.spec.containers`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/7ac1236/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L2119) and [`pod.spec.volumes`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/7ac1236/pkg/api/v1/types.go#L2098).

For an example you need to provide more information about the type you want to merge.

Comment: Where is it "documented"? Been looking several hours for such documentation and found 0 documentation on that. All there is, is the extremely terse "documentation" (if you can call those explanations that feel like 2 half-assed sentences that) on strategic merge patches in general. I am trying to add a volume to an existing deployment through a strategic merge patch and it just won't work. How are the elements you mentioned to be adjusted for the patch to work in the explained scenario?

Comment: Probably this can help someone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165168/can-someone-explain-patchesstrategicmerge

Comment: This is documented here https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-api-machinery/strategic-merge-patch.md