# Can someone explain 'patchesStrategicMerge'

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I see `patchesStrategicMerge`in my kustomization.yaml file, but not getting it clearly, like whats its need or why we require that?

kustomization.yaml

```yaml
resources:
- a.yaml

patchesStrategicMerge:
- b.yaml
- c.yaml
```

I went through this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#customizing and
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-api-machinery/strategic-merge-patch.md

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This comes in handy you *inherit* from some base and want to apply partial changes to said base. That way, you can have one source YAML file and perform different customizations based on it, without having to recreate the entire resource. That is one key selling point of [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/).

The purpose of the `Strategic Merge Patch` is to be able to patch *rich objects* partially, instead of replacing them entirely.

Imagine you have a list, of object.

```yaml
mylist:
 - name: foo
 - name: bar
 - name: baz
```

How could you change one of the items in the list? With a standard merge patch, you could only replace the entire list. But with a strategic merge patch, you can target one element in the list based on some property, in this case only the name makes sense as it's the only property.

```
mylist:
 - $patch: delete
   name: foo
```

In the above example, I used the strategic merge patch to remove the item in the list with the name foo.

Here is another example, suppose I have the following project structure.

```
sample
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── pod.yaml
└── layers
    └── dev
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── patch.yaml
```

In the base, is my full pod definition. While in the layers, I can create multiple layers for different environments, in this case I have only one for dev.

The kustomization.yaml in the base folder looks like this.

```
resources:
 - pod.yaml
```

If I execute the base itself with dry run I get this.

```bash
kubectl apply -k sample/base --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
  - command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
  - image: busybox
    name: sidecar
```

The kustomization.yaml in the dev folder looks like this.

```yaml
bases:
  - ../../base
patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patch.yaml
```

And the patch looks like this. I want to enable debug logging for the sidecar. Thefore I am using a merge directive to change its arguments without changing the image. I also want to keep the nginx container.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  containers:
    - $patch: merge
      name: sidecar
      args: [log-level, debug]
```

```bash
kubectl apply -k sample/layers/dev/ --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - log-level
    - debug
    command:
    - sleep
    - infinity
    image: busybox
    name: sidecar
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx
```

*Note: The command and args don't make much sense, It's just to illustrate the strategic merge patch.*

Answer (score 0):

***patchesStrategicMerge*** is a function used in Kubernetes to apply changes to Kubernetes resources. It's typically utilized when managing configurations via YAML files in Kubernetes using `Kustomize`. For example given this deployment base file:

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nginx
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: nginx
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx:latest
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Kustomization file of the previous deployment.

```yaml
    apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Kustomization

    resources:
    - deployment.yaml
```

In order to apply changes, we will define a deployment with same name and another kustomization file which use patchesStrategicMerge.

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
    spec:
      replicas: 6
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            env: 
            - name: ENV
              value: "production"
```

Kustomization file of the previous deployment

```yaml
    apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: Kustomization

    namePrefix: prod-

    bases:
    - ../../base

    patchesStrategicMerge:
    - deployment.yaml
```

**Note**: The usage for patchesStrategicMerge in this example is to add an environment variable to the deployment as well as updating the number of replicas. ***../../base*** is the path for the original kustomization file.